# How to persist spring-boot metrics as log?

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot, java-8

I am running a spring-boot application, that measures the standard and custom metrics. Now I want those metrics to be persisted in elasticsearch for further examination. I have a functioning ELK-stack in place, so the obvious solution to me was persisting the measures in a log file and let filebeat collect it.

I have found an [example](https://kielczewski.eu/2015/01/application-metrics-with-spring-boot-actuator/), that could have achieved this, but it was using `MetricRepository`, which is no longer supported in java 8.

The [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-metric-writers) is not helpful. All shown examples use some proprietary format or are writing into a database.

Can anyone please provide a way to persist metrics as log files?

Comment: The first 2 lines of the documentation you link to explain what you need to do. I also wonder where you got the idea that `MetricRepository` is deprecated, it still isn't in Spring Boot 1.5.2 nor is it for Spring Boot 2.0.0. Also if you use Elastic there already is an [exporter](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-metrics-reporter-java) for that although it requires an additional library.

Comment: "The old MetricRepository and its InMemoryMetricRepository implementation are not used by default if you are on Java 8 or if you are using Dropwizard metrics." - As stated in the first info box in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-metric-repositories).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you just have to write a `MetricWriter` implementation and mark the bean with `@ExportMetricWriter`  Should be a piece of cake. Implement the three methods by just writing to the log and that's it.

Something like:

```
@Component
@ExportMetricWriter
public class MyMetricWriter implements MetricWriter, Closeable {

  private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MyMetricWriter.class);


@Override
public void increment(Delta<?> delta) {
    // record increment to log
}

@Override
public void set(Metric<?> value) {
    // record set metric to log
}

@Override
public void reset(String name) {
    // Not implemented
}

@Override
public void close() {
    /// ...
     }
}
```

The docs mentioned a few others you can refer to their implementations for inspiration.

Comment: ExportMetricWriter was not found and MetricWriter was extended not implemented, couldnt use this solution. any updates? i am using Spring boot 2